# Intercepting/Accessing yield value inside nested calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Imagine having following method calls:

```
parse() -> parseProductPage() -> parseUser()     (indirectly?) -> process_item()
                              -> parseCategory() (indirectly?) -> process_item()
                              -> parseProduct()  (indirectly?) -> process_item()
```

process_item() belongs to some pipeline class and is responsible for inserting each item into database and returning corresponding ID (dynamically generated by MongoDB, not present before insert). All other methods belong to the spider class and yield recursively.

Now what I want, is to access every ID on the way back, but the problem is that the yielded value is only accessible to the initial caller (parent? of parse()).

Since process_item() has access to the calling spider, one way to solve this would be to write each of these IDs to corresponding member variable, but this seems to me like a poor design architecture where many things could go wrong. Are there any alternatives?

@Edit I guess I could transfer the relationship-creation logic to the pipeline, but is it really meant to be that way?

Answer (score 0):

If `parseProduct` requires input from `parseUser` or the other way around, you must make your MongoDB client part of your spider, which requires some Twisted knowledge and possibly a Twisted-based MongoDB client not to block Scrapy during MongoDB requests.

Alternatively, it may be easier to simply generate an output file with the raw data and write a separate script that parses that file and sends the data to MongoDB as desired.

Comment: I did come up with 3 alternatives, among which is the one that requires overriding framework code in order to create a pipeline back. I will certainly post solutions to all of them when I'm done with what I'm currently working on. I appreciate your help!